# VBA Data validation does not work when copy/paste from another cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have dynamic data validation across a range of cells that updates the target cell every time one is selected. For example, I have a column with the header "University" that is pulling data from a University list on another page. The validation works great when typing in the cell or when selecting from the drop-down.

However, when I copy an invalid value from another cell (e.g. 55555) and paste it in the University column, it allows me to press enter and move to the next cell without giving me an alert.

```
Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
Dim strList As String

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim RefRng As Range, RngFind As Range, NewRng As Range, hdr
    Dim RefList As Range, c As Range, rngHeaders As Range, msg

    On Error GoTo ErrHandling

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Candidate Picklist")

    'only deal with the selected cell(s)
    Set NewRng = Application.Intersect(Me.Range("A12:T101"), Target)
    If Not NewRng Is Nothing Then

        Set rngHeaders = ws.Range("A11:ZZ11")

        For Each c In NewRng
            c.Validation.Delete 'delete previous validation
            hdr = Me.Cells(11, c.Column).Value

            If Len(hdr) > 0 Then
                Set RngFind = rngHeaders.Find(hdr, , xlValues, xlWhole)
                'matched header?
                If Not RngFind Is Nothing Then

                    Set RefList = ws.Range(RngFind.Offset(1, 0), _
                                           RngFind.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown))
                        With c.Validation
                                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
                                     AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                                     Formula1:="='" & ws.Name & "'!" & RefList.Address
                               .IgnoreBlank = True
                                .InCellDropdown = True
                                .InputTitle = ""
                                .ErrorTitle = ""
                                .InputMessage = ""
                                .ErrorMessage = ""
                                .ShowInput = True
                                .ShowError = True
                        End With
                End If 'matched header
            End If 'has header

        Next c
    End If 'in required range
```

Comment: I just took a quick peak but at a glance... In changing that cell you "reset" the validation by deleting it, then put it back on.  Meaning the value contained never actually went through the validation process.

Comment: One way is to do only PasteSpecial (which can preserve the validation), and then use event code to check that the value pasted conforms to the underlying validation rules.  If the type of paste is not under your control, you will need to intercept the paste events and convert them to paste special. [Catching Paste Operations](http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/catchpaste.asp?AllComments=True) by Jan Karel Pieterse purports to do this, but I have not tested it myself.

Comment: What is this Subroutine (or a part of it) that you are showing here? What triggers it to run to begin with?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld That is a Gem.  I wonder if it works.

Comment: Are you using the `Worksheet_Change` event?

Comment: @Gene and Macro Man I am using a Worksheet_SelectionChange event, as i want the validation to update for a given cell in my range as soon as it's clicked on. One interesting thing is I need to click enter twice before I can exit the cell. RonRosenfeld, I will check out that method -- looks involved, but hopefully it can solve this problem!

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I tested Jan's code but it hasn't worked for me so far. When I copy and Paste, then hit Enter, it doesn't do anything at first except clear the "copy range" dotted lines around the source data. Then when I hit Enter again, it moves to the next cell, but there's no error. Incidentally though, I tried right-click, Paste Special, Values and still didn't see my validation fire.

Comment: I wouldn't expect the validation to fire. By doing Paste Special, the advantage is that you don't destroy the validation rules in the cell.  You still have to check that the entry is valid by comparing it with the validation rules.  You can do that with event code.  The advantage of Jan's code is that it should convert Paste into Paste Special.  But you still have to recheck that the entry is valid.  As I wrote above.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I apologize for my noobishness, but can you clarify what you mean by "use event code" here? I am not sure how I can make a worksheet_change event fire from the "IsValidationOK()" function.